# How to create Checklist Windows beside any wizard

Tags: eclipse-rcp, wizard

I have wizard having 7 pages. I would like to show check list  something like when we install any Windows os ,it shows some check list that currently you are on this process and you still have more process to finish it. So something i would like to show from first page that you still have 6 more process so wait till that time and i can show checkbox and tick it. Please help me out how can i show such tracker ?

Comment: There isn't any standard support for this. You would have to write your own extended version of `WizardDialog`.

Comment: can we customise wizard dialog's button bar composite area  where can show something like tracking ?

Comment: Again you would have to use an extended version of `WizardDialog`.

Comment: other way round it's done by adding it in composite and setting it into Border Layouts. That's resolved now.